# Apply a selected function from a list of functions

Tags: common-lisp

I want to select from a list of functions. And apply a choosen function to arguments.

```
 (defvar fn '(#'(lambda (x) (* x x)) #'(lambda (x) (+ x x))))
```

```
 (apply (nth 1 fn) '(5))
```

Above code does not work what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fn` is not a list of functions. Since you quoted the list, none of the function expressions are evaluated. So you just have a list of lists of the form `(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X) ...))`.

Use `list` to make the list and evaluate all the arguments:

```
(defvar fn (list #'(lambda (x) (* x x)) #'(lambda (x) (+ x x))))
```

Or use backquote and comma:

```
(defvar fn `(,#'(lambda (x) (* x x)) ,#'(lambda (x) (+ x x))))
```

Comment: Barmar, Thanks very much, I'll have to think a bit, but it worked:-) Your answer was, for me, exactly spot on, given my current limited knowledge of CL:-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Lisp one can interactively explore these data structures:

```
CL-USER 50 > '(#'(lambda (x) (* x x)) #'(lambda (x) (+ x x)))
((FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X) (* X X)))
 (FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X) (+ X X))))
```

Above is a list. What type are the elements:

```
CL-USER 51 > (mapcar #'type-of *)
(CONS CONS)
```

Above says that the elements are not functions, but cons cells.

We now evaluate the list elements:

```
CL-USER 52 > (mapcar #'eval **)
(#<anonymous interpreted function 40600010FC>
 #<anonymous interpreted function 406000112C>)
```

What type are these elements of? Now they are functions:

```
CL-USER 53 > (mapcar #'type-of *)
(FUNCTION FUNCTION)
```

Answer (score 0):

`'(#'(lambda (x) (* x x)) #'(lambda (x) (+ x x))))` is a quoted expression. `fn` is a list of symbols in your example.

You actually want the `lambda`s to be evaluated to `function`s so you would remove the quote and write:

```lisp
(defvar *fn* (list (lambda (x) (* x x)) (lambda (x) (+ x x))))
```

Now each `function` object can indeed be used as argument to [apply](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```lisp
(apply (car *fn*) (list 3))
=> 9
```

[funcall](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm#funcall) also exists. See if you can understand how it differs from [apply](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) by reading the HyperSpec. You would call it like this:

```lisp
(funcall (cadr *fn*) 3)
=> 6
```

Comment: Thanks. My neurons are now better wired. They now realize that (list ...) is not the same as '(...).

Comment: Indeed. Using `quote` is legitimate when you need to write a constant list of self-evaluating objects (see the CLHS). Numbers and strings are examples of self-evaluating objects, but expressions that evaluate to numbers or strings are not. So `(= 3 (car '(3)))` and `(string= "aaa" (car '("aaa")))` are both true.